# how to open multiple forms without closing other forms

Tags: c#

I am trying to open two or more than two forms without closing the previous one 
but whenever I try to open next form, the previous form goes behind the screen and then only the next form opens. The forms are opened using the form.Show() method.
[This is the main form of my project. When I open more than one form the form goes behind the panels of this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiNqa.png)

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Both question are of same project. In the previous case I was using MDI container. But since the idea of MDi container was not helpful, I turned down the idea.

Comment: My solution is using two forms ion the same class.  When I open the 2nd for I do not close it, instead just make it invisible so that data can be transferred between forms.  I did use container so you must be looking at a different answer on the posting.

Answer (score 0):

From the parent Form, you can open child Form via:(

```
childForm.Show(this);
```

The child form will appear on top for parent form and will not allow user to get back to parent form, before he closes child form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: appreciate your help, but here in my case, I am not using the parent and child relation. So can you provide other alternatives